# How to fetch exactly the same NSManagedObject I just saved to Core Data?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, magicalrecord

Simply I do it like this:

```
var objectID: NSManagedObjectID!

MagicalRecord.save(block: { context in

    if let dictionary = (response as? [AnyHashable: Any])?["data"] as? [AnyHashable: Any] {

        if let itemInfo = dictionary["item"] as? [AnyHashable: Any] {
            objectID = Item.create(with: itemInfo, in: context).objectID //here objectID is NOT nil
        }
    }

}, completion: { error in

    let item = Item.find(with: objectID) //here item is nil
    completion(item, Error(error: error))
})
```

I also created extension:

```
extension NSManagedObject {

    class func find(with objectID: NSManagedObjectID) -> Self? {
        return mr_findFirst(with: NSPredicate(format: "SELF = %@", objectID))
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know what "magic" MagicalRecord does in `Item.create`, but generally, a newly created object has a temporary ID which changes when the context is saved. There is an `obtainPermanentIDs(for:)` method to get the permanent IDs before saving.

Comment: how do I call that method? Is there any way to fetch object saved to core data? I could not use any property of my object because there are a lot of the same object with the same properties, I need exactly that instance I just saved. Is it possible?

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext/1506793-obtainpermanentids.